# jBehave NullPointerException for step method

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I have the following jBehave story / scenario;

```
Scenario: some info validation
When I enter the population as <global_target_pop> and submit
Then I should see validation message <message> for <field>

Examples:
| field | global_target_pop | message |
| targetPopulation | a1 | Population should be an Integer |
```

The corresponding step method is as below;

```
@Then("Then I should see validation message <message> for <field>")
    public void checkValidationMessageForField(String message, @Named("value") String reason, @Named("field") String fieldName) {

    }
```

However, I am getting NullPointerException for this particular step. Below is the stack trace;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.parameterPosition(StepCreator.java:404)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.parameterForPosition(StepCreator.java:310)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.parameterValuesForStep(StepCreator.java:296)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.access$1000(StepCreator.java:36)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.parametriseStep(StepCreator.java:639)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:592)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner$FineSoFar.run(StoryRunner.java:535)
```

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Give explicit names to all parameters in your method declaration:

```
 public void checkValidationMessageForField(
     @Names("message") String message, 
     @Named("value") String reason, 
     @Named("field") String fieldName) {
 }
```

If table examples are used to parametrize the scenario, namely parameters using '< name >' syntax in the step, then all parameters in the matching java method must use named parameters (parameters with @Named annotation):

http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/parametrised-scenarios.html

> One important difference to underline in using table examples is that
>   they require **named parameters** for the step candidates to be matched to
>   Java methods. The named parameters allow the parameters to be injected
>   using the table row values with the corresponding header name, instead
>   of being extracted from the annotation pattern match. As such, **the
>   step annotation pattern must hold the verbatim textual step**, e.g.:
>
> ```
>        @Given("a stock of <symbol> and a <threshold>") public void
>        aStock(@Named("symbol") String symbol, @Named("threshold") double
>        threshold) {
>                    // ... }
> ```

---

There also is a problem with "value" parameter - it is declared in the java method using a`@Named("value")` annotation, but doesn't appear in the scenario.
You need to assign a value to this parameter, either in the examples table, or using a meta tag in the scenario:

```
Examples:
| field            | global_target_pop | message       | value      |
| targetPopulation | a1                | Population... | some value |
```

or:

```
Meta:
@value some value

Scenario: some info validation
When I enter the population as <global_target_pop> and submit
Then I should see validation message <message> for <field>

Examples:
| field | global_target_pop | message |
| targetPopulation | a1 | Population should be an Integer |
```